# Redis client not executing on GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm trying to get/set in redis using nodejs, I've ensured its async/await as per the docs but from my code below im only ever hitting console log 1.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

```
const Redis = require('redis')

const redisClient = Redis.createClient({
    url: 'redis://*****:*****@redis-******.cloud.redislabs.com:16564'
})
redisClient.connect()
redisClient.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
redisClient.set('name', 'Steph'); // THIS WORKS FINE


router.get('/market/product/:slug', async (req,res) => {
    const productId = req.params.slug
    console.log('console log one')

    await redisClient.get(productId, async (error, history) => {
        console.log('console log two')
        if (error) console.error(error)
        if (productId != null) {
            console.log('console log three')
            res.json(JSON.parse(history))
        } else {
            console.log('console log four')
            await ProductPrices.find({productId: productId})
                .lean()
                .sort({date: 1})
                .exec((err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(400).json({
                            error: errorHandler(err)
                        })
                    }

                    redisClient.set(productId, JSON.stringify(data))
                    res.json(data)
                })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: What Redis client package are you using?

Comment: Just the basics first how is the redisClient defined? Also, have you called the connect method on the client?

Comment: I'm using redis npm package and defined above the code the redisClient = redis.createClient() and im passing in the url that links to my redislabs database. I'm also doing redisClient.connect() and logging out if there's an error on connect

Comment: Just to be sure, it connects, right?

Comment: yeah it connects if i do a simple redisClient.set('name', 'Steph') outside of my .get it works fine. I'll update the code to show the connect commands

Answer (score 1):

I went to the documentation of the package you stated you used in the comments of the question. I couldn't find any place where callbacks were used.

Try

```
let history= await redisClient.get(productId)
if (!history) {
    if (productId != null) {
        console.log('console log three')
        res.json(JSON.parse(history))
    } else {
        console.log('console log four')
        await ProductPrices.find({ productId: productId })
            .lean()
            .sort({ date: 1 })
            .exec((err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        error: errorHandler(err)
                    })
                }

                redisClient.set(productId, JSON.stringify(data))
                res.json(data)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: res.json(JSON.parse(history))  would not work because you need the call back to get the data (history in this case). I'm actually following this youtube explanation where call backs are used successfully: https://youtu.be/jgpVdJB2sKQ?t=1179

Comment: @StephanieCherry current versions of the Redis client don't support callbacks anymore. Instead of using `product` as a variable name, use `history`.

Comment: @StephanieCherry I forgot to change the variables. This should work.